# An API based monitoring tool to monitor health of a service running on linux

Tags: linux, service, health-monitoring

I have a Python service running on Linux device. The service is getting hung every couple of days. I am looking for a cloud monitoring tool, to which the service can keep sending heartbeat information every 2 minutes. And, if the tool doesn't receive this heart beat continuously for 10 minutes, the tool should raise an alert to mail.

Please let me know if there are any tools like that.